# Is there any way to set Gmail app as the default mail client in iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gmail, configuration-profiles

I want to be able to one-click email links from apps such as Twitter, Safari and Instapaper. Is this possible if I'm using Gmail and not Apple's Mail app?

Do I have to set Gmail as the default mail client? Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible on iOS 13 and lower. (Or iPadOS 13 or lower)

In order to utilize email functionalities from within apps, you will have to enable the Apple Mail app. I recommend turning off all notifications for Mail if you want to use the Gmail app as your primary iPhone mail client.

Comment: There are rumours that Apple is considering allowing this starting with iOS 14. https://www.theverge.com/2020/2/20/21145227/apple-third-party-apps-default-report-browser-mail-music-homepod

Answer (score 10):

To give a very short answer: **No**, this is not possible.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: Also, is there any way to get around this? ie, a workaround so you can "mail links" directly from ios 6 apps such as Twitter, Safari, NYTimes, etc?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be possible with a jailbreak. I am almost to the point of jailbreaking for this feature...

Comment: [Sparrow+](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=sparrowplusDp) claims that it can change the default mail app. So technically that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you are using the Gmail app and Chrome browser (i.e. when clicking on the mail icon in a NY Times story you are browsing in Chrome), but I don't think you can enable it by default in other apps.

Answer (score 1):

I just added outlook to the apps when sending from Safari and it now appears as an option. Not quite default but good enough

Answer (score 0):

I do have a jailbroken iPhone 4s and unfortunately I cannot find any app to add this much desired functionality in any Cydia repository.

So at the moment I'd say it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice workaround, it may be a good solution:
[Can I use gmail as default client for sharing photos from camera roll or links from safari?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5098990?start=0&tstart=0)