# Change default email application - iPadOS

Tags: mail.app, gmail, notes.app, ipados

When I type on Notes.app, it is useful to have clickable email links as follows:

[image]

Whenever I click this link, it wants to take me to Mail.app, I don’t have it installed so it shows this message:

[image]

I want to use Gmail.app to open these email links, is it possible to change the default app to Gmail?

Comment: @ankii no it doesn't, the question is 8 years old. There could be a different answer

Comment: I should go write *Update 2020: still not possbile* ;p Seriously though, see this comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57020/is-there-any-way-to-set-gmail-app-as-the-default-mail-client-in-iphone-and-ipad#comment520362_74791

Comment: @Daniil we close questions and point them to the same ones. Whether the answer is there or not doesn’t weigh into the close decision. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates for details. I’m voting this up, too since it has great photos that will help people find the no answer and possibly add a new answer if there is a yes or workaround.